# Grunt need compass installed in system PATH Warning

Tags: eclipse, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I want to install Yeoman, Grunt and bower to my node project.

I made a node project in Eclipse (using the nodeclipse plugin) and navigated to the project folder
(which is H:\Eclipse Workspace\YoTest) in cmd and typed in:

```
npm install yo -g

npm install generator-webapp -g

yo webapp
```

selected: Sass (with compass), in cmd

And then typed:

```
grunt serve
```

to run the webapp.

I get the following error message:

```
Done, without errors.
    Warning: Running "compass:server" (compass) task
Warnin: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for
 this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass
Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings. Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

How do I fix this so that I can run my node project with grunt?

PS: I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the problem, but I also get the following errors on line 1-27 in my package.json:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - strings must use singlequote
    - strings must use singlequote
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "yotest2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-bower-install": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-mocha": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-modernizr": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-newer": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
    "time-grunt": "~0.2.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  }
}
```

I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The warning seems to say it all.

1. If you're on OS X or Linux you probably already have Ruby installed; test with `ruby -v` in your terminal. When you've confirmed you have Ruby installed, run `gem update --system && gem install compass` to install Compass and Sass.
2. If that doesn't help, then install the `grunt-contrib-compass` package with the instructions at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass

Comment: Im on Windows. I have ruby installed and also Compass and Sass. I also
follow the grunt-contrib-compass tutorial but I still cant make it work. Only way I can make it works is with grunt serve --force ofcourse but then it doesnt load css etc.

Comment: +1 thanks Eric,- @Rockyy, I just had to run `gem update --system && gem install compass` from a windows machine to do this.

Comment: You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory. I got the above error. using sudo makes it stuck.

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer?  The question clearly states he's using Windows.  Unless Microsoft is now referring to Windows as "OS X", I think you must be talking about some other fruity OS.

Comment: On Windows make sure that `Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH`. I had to restart the IDE to pick up the updated environment.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled for hours with this same error message when running a gulp watch, and despite installing, reinstalling, rebooting, it would still show up.

Got it working by uninstalling all my packages :

```
sudo gem uninstall bundler bundle compass sass compass-core compass-import-once
```

And installing bundle only

```
sudo gem install bundle bundler
```

And then run the command that magically installed everything I needed :

```
$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing sass 3.4.9
Installing sassy-maps 0.4.0
Installing breakpoint 2.5.0
Installing hitimes 1.2.2
Installing timers 4.0.1
Installing celluloid 0.16.0
Using chunky_png 1.3.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Installing compass-core 1.0.1
Using compass-import-once 1.0.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.4
Using ffi 1.9.6
Using rb-inotify 0.9.5
Installing compass 1.0.1
Installing json 1.8.1
Installing listen 2.8.3
Installing thor 0.19.1
Installing fontcustom 1.3.7
Installing modular-scale 2.0.5
Installing normalize-scss 3.0.2
Installing sass-css-importer 1.0.0.beta.0
Installing sassy-buttons 0.2.6
Installing susy 2.1.3
Using bundler 1.8.0
Bundle complete! 9 Gemfile dependencies, 24 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from compass:
    Compass is charityware. If you love it, please donate on our behalf at http://umdf.org/compass Thanks!
Post-install message from fontcustom:
>> Thanks for installing Font Custom! Please ensure that fontforge is installed before compiling any icons. Visit <http://fontcustom.com> for instructions.
```

Now, don't ask me why, but it all works :-)

Hope that can help anybody out there, I really struggled on this one ...

Answer (score 0):

Just need to write on console -> (or sudo )gem install compass ,because the npm command wouldn´t do anything

Comment: It gets stuck and nothing goes ahead. :( You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Search for installed ruby version
`ruby -v`.
If present 
update gems using  `sudo gem update --system`
else install rvm with ruby using 
`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

Then install the Xcode Command Line Tools
   `xcode-select --install` .
This will take some time.

Now install compass using `sudo gem install compass`.
For me this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby and Ruby Gems ought to be installed which in turn facilitate the installation of Sass and compass. Check this out http://hecktechsolutions.blogspot.in/2015/03/installation-of-gems-compass-and-sass.html